# JSON Object parse javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object -

```
rows = [{name:"testname1" , age:"25"}, {name:"testname2" , age:"26"}]
```

I would like to extract the name information and put it into a variable like this.

```
name = "testname1, testname2";
```

Comment: name = testname1, testname2

Comment: You don't have a JSON object (that's a JavaScript array), and it isn't clear what you want.

Comment: Could it be that you want `name = "testname1, testname2";`, i.e. concatenate the `name`s of all objects in the array?

Comment: i need this  array's name comma separated.

Comment: Yes, i want this . name = "testname1, testname2";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var name = rows.map(function(r){
  return r.name
}).join(', ');
```

The above code will store the string `testname1, testname2` into the `name` variable.

For more information on the `.map` function please [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: What does this code do? I'm not sure supplying a snippet without some sort of explanation is a good thing...

Comment: he said he need result as name = testname1, testname2; so this will store  the string testname1, testname2 into name variable.

Comment: I thought so. Not trying to be rude, but could you put the explanation in the answer?